# Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport4', Only happened to 1 PC but not on other PCs

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a VS2013 (written in C# x32) desktop application accessing a hosted SQL Server 2012. It has a report that has 4 subreports. After I installed it onto a few PCs, One of the PC has the above issue but the other PCs display the report correctly. The strange thing is the problem PC display this error half-way through subreport4. All PCs are running on Windows 7 (x32/64). I am really at a lost as to how to find out why it happened only to 1 PC which is basically similar to the rest.

The coding of the report is reproduced below:-

```
    public partial class ReportProject : Form
{

    cl_Class1 mySettings = new cl_Class1();
    SqlConnection conReport = new SqlConnection();

    public ReportProject()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "Test Report";
        // Add a handler for SubreportProcessing
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(LocalReport_SubreportProcessing);
    }

    // data set at the class level to access by all methods
    DataSet dsReport = new dsTestReport();

    private void ReportProject_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // connection to database
        conReport.ConnectionString = mySettings.myConnString;
        SqlCommand cmdReport = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader drReport;

        try
        {
            // open connection
            conReport.Open();
            cmdReport.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdReport.Connection = conReport;

            // get query string from builder
            string strMain = "aaaaa";
            string strSub1 = "bbbbb";
            string strSub2 = "ccccc";
            string strSub3 = "ddddd"; 

            cmdReport.CommandText = strMain + strSub1 + strSub2 + strSub3;

            // execute query and load result to dataset
            drReport = cmdReport.ExecuteReader();
            dsReport.Load(drReport, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, dsReport.Tables[0], dsReport.Tables[1], dsReport.Tables[2], dsReport.Tables[3]);
            // close connection
            drReport.Close();
            conReport.Close();

            // prepare report for view
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "myProgram.rptMain.rdlc";

            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
            rds.Name = "DataSet1";

            rds.Value = dsReport.Tables[0];
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

            // preview the report
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            if (conReport.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conReport.Close();
            }
        }

    }
    void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {  
        string myReportName = e.ReportPath;

        if (myReportName == "rptSubReport1") 
            {
                e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dsReport.Tables[1]));
            }
        if (myReportName == "rptSubReport2")
            {
                e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dsReport.Tables[2]));
            }
        if (myReportName == "rptSubReport3")
        {
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dsReport.Tables[3]));
        }
        if (myReportName == "rptSubReport4")
        {
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dsReport.Tables[3]));
        }

    }
}
```

NOTE: SubReport3 and SubReport4 uses the same dataset (dsReport.Tables[3])

Would apprecate advise/help to resolve this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suppose we would need to see SubReport4 and what it's doing. My first guess would be regional settings though, check date formats for the PC not working and compare with working one.

Comment: I have changed the date format as suggested on the development machine and SubReport4 renders correctly too, so I don't think date format is the cause. SubReport4's querry string is based on a sql view that returns all string fields and SubReport4 rdlc consists of displaying 5 fields (all string) from the sql view. What puzzled me is that SubReport3 and SubReport4 both use the same query and yet SubReport3 displays correctly but not SubReport4.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, I uninstalled the reportviewer runtime from this PC (this is the only PC with a copy of the reportviewer). After the uninstall, the report now runs correctly! although this seemed to resolve the issue, I am still puzzled why this is the case - maybe there is something in the reportviewer runtime that conflict with the compiled software.